# How to filter results in Firebase using timestamp? Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on an blog app in which i need to filter the data according to the time, i want data's in decending order from current time but don't know which filter e.g. "StartAt","EndBefore" to use for getting new post data.

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("news")
        .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .  //Timestamp.now() want news lower than my timestamp
        .limit(2)
        .get()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well i got the answer here i need to use WhereLessThan

```
.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .whereLessThan("timestamp",Timestamp.now())
        .limit(2)
        .get()
```